# How would I loop my program 5 seconds after the answer is given

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;    

public class Printer   {
   public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception  {
   while(true){
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input = br.readLine(); 
    double number = Double.valueOf(input).doubleValue();
    System.out.println("Enter second number:");
    input = br.readLine();
    double number1= Double.valueOf(input).doubleValue();


    System.out.println("Enter operator(+, -, *, /): ");
    input = br.readLine();    //"+" "-" "*" "/"
    if (input.compareTo ("+") == 0)
    {
       System.out.println("Answer is: " + (number + number1));
       break;
    }
    else if (input.compareTo ("-") == 0)
    {
       System.out.println("Answer is: " + (number - number1));
       break;
      }
    else if (input.compareTo ("*") == 0)
    {
       System.out.println("Answer is: " + (number * number1));
       break;
    }
    else if (input.compareTo ("/") == 0)
    {
       System.out.println("Answer is: " + (number / number1));
       break;
    }

   }
 }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "loop my program 5 seconds"?

Answer (score 2):

You can always try something like this to wait for five seconds

```
try { Thread.sleep(5000L); } catch(InterruptedException ex) {}
```

Comment: Only need to catch interrupted exception.

Answer (score 1):

don't know if I understood, but you should try something like : Thread.sleep(5000) if you want your program to sleep for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Use Thread.sleep(5000L) to make your program sleep for 5 seconds.